# How does Google Maps see my hardware details (and decides to disable 3D view)?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps’ 3D view is not supported on my Laptop (Thinkpad X200).

- How does Google Maps recognize/decide that my hardware through my browser is not “supported”?
- How to circumvent this check?

I’m pretty sure that other than glitches and endless slowness, there is no real support missing in the chain. My Linux Chromium and X11 supports all acceleration interfaces.

Comment: It's either via the user-agent string (which you can find a way to spoof) or via checking to see if your browser can support certain functions, which would be harder to trick. I expect only Google engineers can answer this, though.

Comment: http://browserspy.dk/ can help you see what information your computer makes available to websites.

Answer (score 1):

Google seems to have updated it’s [support page](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3096703?hl=en) to point to the [technical details](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists) behind this: it’s all about WebGL and a blacklisting-feature included in the browsers.

E.g. for Chrome you can find PCI IDs (e.g. of my graphic card 8086:2a42 Intel Mobile GM45) and that it checks which mesa driver version is running from [this file](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/config/software_rendering_list_json.cc).